# SELECT (Count? SUM?) with ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am build a report, the output should be like (example):

```
['11/2012', 5, 2, 0]
['10/2012', 7, 1, 0]
['09/2012', 2, 3, 0]
['08/2012', 0, 0, 1]
['07/2012', 0, 2, 1]
['06/2012', 2, 1, 0]
['05/2012', 3, 1, 1]
['04/2012', 2, 2, 1]
['03/2012', 5, 0, 0]
['02/2012', 7, 1, 0]
['01/2012', 2, 0, 0]
['12/2011', 3, 0, 1]
```

For the month part, I need to get the actual month and than list one year back. I have done this with this code:

```
<%
    DataAtual_PeriodoInicial= Now
    DataFinal_PeriodoInicial= DateAdd("m", -13, Now)
    DO WHILE Datediff("m", DataAtual_PeriodoInicial, DataFinal_PeriodoInicial) <> 0
%>
    ['<% Response.Write(Right("0" & Month(DataAtual_PeriodoInicial), 2)) %>/<% Response.Write(Year(DataAtual_PeriodoInicial)) %>', X, Y, Z]<br>
<%
    DataAtual_PeriodoInicial= DateAdd("m", -1, DataAtual_PeriodoInicial)
    LOOP
%>
```

So this is generating:

```
['11/2012', X, Y, Z]
['10/2012', X, Y, Z]
['09/2012', X, Y, Z]
['08/2012', X, Y, Z]
['07/2012', X, Y, Z]
['06/2012', X, Y, Z]
['05/2012', X, Y, Z]
['04/2012', X, Y, Z]
['03/2012', X, Y, Z]
['02/2012', X, Y, Z]
['01/2012', X, Y, Z]
['12/2011', X, Y, Z]
```

Now I have to throw some numbers instead of X, Y, and Z. I have a table with data like:

```
11  2012    X
10  2012    X
10  2012    X
10  2012    X
10  2012    Y
10  2012    Y
10  2012    Z
10  2012    Z
10  2012    Z
9   2012    X
9   2012    X
9   2012    X
9   2012    Y
9   2012    Z
9   2012    Z
8   2012    X
8   2012    X
8   2012    Y
8   2012    Y
8   2012    Y
8   2012    Y
8   2012    Y
...
```

And I start with this select:

```
SELECT
    datepart(month,SentDate) AS Mes,
    datepart(year,SentDate) AS Ano,
    EventType
FROM
    SomeTable
ORDER BY
    SentDate DESC
```

I tried some group by, but didn't sucessed. Do I need some kind of Count? SUM? And how can i finish the come to have the output like the one in the top of this question?

Thanks!

Comment: You have labelled multiple things 'X', and multiple things 'Y' and multiple things 'Z'. You haven't put column names in your table. Your SQL wouldn't work with the example data you have provided.

Comment: This was just an example to explain my needs. Gaby understood it in a flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    datepart(month,SentDate) AS Mes,
    datepart(year,SentDate) AS Ano,
    sum(CASE WHEN EventType = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) X,
    sum(CASE WHEN EventType = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Y,
    sum(CASE WHEN EventType = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Z
FROM
    SomeTable
GROUP BY
    datepart(month,SentDate),
    datepart(year,SentDate)
ORDER BY
    Ano DESC,
    Mes DESC
    SentDate DESC
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93a11/23/0

---

You could also use a PIVOT table

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    datepart(month,SentDate) AS Mes,
    datepart(year,SentDate) AS Ano,
    EventType
  FROM 
    SomeTable
 ) grouped
PIVOT (COUNT(eventType) for EventType in ([X],[Y],[Z])) AS pivoted
ORDER BY
  Ano DESC,
  Mes DESC
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93a11/16/0